# download large ibook file from safari (ipad)

Tags: ajax, html, ipad, ibooks

i have a large ibook file and i will share it with my friends via download link (dropbox,mediafire ..etc) so they can download it from safari.
But, how can i show download status for the file because they will wait very long time.
mega.co.nz
have good download status progress but only work on PC

thanks